# Unable to cache the rigidbody component as mentioned in the spaceshooter tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following the unity3D spaceshooter tutorial series. It was made for Unity 4, I believe and when Unity 5 was released, they released a document of all the changes that we had to do to follow the tutorial in Unity 5.

I am trying to access the rigidbody component of the gameobject.

I tried

```
  using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    void FixedUpdate(){
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

        _rb.position = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    }

    }
```

However, the console gave me this error.

```
Assets/_Scripts/PlayerController.cs(12,17): error CS0103: The name `_rb' does not exist in the current context
```

I am very new to C Sharp. So, I do not know even the basic syntax.

It is pointing towards the first line included.

Comment: Post your whole code. it looks like you have a typo in your code.

Comment: "I do not know even the basic syntax." you can find very many tutorials on the net.  Good luck with your hobby programming, it's great fun.  It is a huge waste of time for people on here who kindly spend tie trying to answer your questions if you do not paste in the actual code you are using, all of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not suitable for tutorials.

Comment: I posted my complete code. I am very familiar with other languages like python , php and swift. I am learning Unity where a code didn't work. So, this is not off topic. It just happened to be a code of a tutorial.

Comment: Python is not the same with C#. Please learn C# before using Unity or you will be asking questions like this. You code shows that you did not declare _rb. I fixed it but do yourself a favor and learn C#.

Comment: Got it working. I didn't specify the object type while initalising the variable. I didn't know rigidbody was an object type.

Comment: NO. You did not declare it and while using  it.

Comment: Oh. ^I didn't realise you made that change.

Comment: I can just use Rigidbody _rb = GetComponent<>() It does both.

Comment: DECLARATION AND INITIALIZATION ARE BOTH DIFFERENT STUFF. You did not declare it. You only initialized it. Please close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a **typo** in your code. Somewhere in your code, you have 
**_rb** instead **rb**.

Change **_rb** to **rb**.

That's probably on line 12. Post the whole code in **PlayerController** script if that's not the case.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
Rigidbody _rb; //DECLARE _rb
    void FixedUpdate(){
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

        _rb.position = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, No it wasn't a typo. I updated it. saw someone use it in a program online so, I put an underscore before the variable name. Sadly, it didn't work.

Comment: Where is _rb declared? You didn't post that part. Please update your code again.

Comment: I'm sorry, thats the whole script. Do we have to declare it somewhere. I thought It'd be instantiated when I call that function.

Comment: You changed your code to be _rb. Make sure that you declared it as Rigidbody _rb instead of Rigidbody rb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106106/discussion-between-quicksillver-and-programmer).